# Getting "Show More Reviews" text using Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I am trying to get the source of an HTML page after "Show More Reviews" on https://www.capterra.com/p/155563/Freshsales/reviews/ url but I am failing to even get partial data.

I have been able to parse all the data which has different links and clicks which open different pages but the same page data has been out of my reach. Not an HTML guy so it is a bit difficult in understanding the button click.

After reading a few posts I think this task is impossible with beautiful soup so it has to be done with Selenium. Please suggest

I am sharing the image after which I want to get the data.[image: After Show More Reviews]

Comment: please provide the code where you are trying to click the button

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use xpath or css:**

**xpath:**

```
//div[contains(@class,"MoreReviewButton")]/button
```

**CSS**

```
div[class *= MoreReviewButton] > button
```

### Both are equalent and are searching for div element containing class with "MoreReviewButton" and then find the direct button child inside it. But the page seems to need double click and doesn't work with single click:

so use:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class *= MoreReviewButton] > button")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",elem)   


a = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class *= MoreReviewButton]>button")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a).double_click().perform()
```

or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class *= MoreReviewButton] > button")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",elem)   


a = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class *= MoreReviewButton]>button")))

a.click()
a.click()
```

Comment: I tried with your way but I kept getting None type element at
"elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class *= MoreReviewButton] > button")"

However I have now resolved the issue by a simple API get request where I am able to all the details!!
thanks!!